# Como conseguir "currentLocation" dentro de uma webview

Tags: android, runtime, geolocalização

Tenho um app que roda uma webview e dentro dessa webview tem uma opção de obter a localização atual do usuário, que, por algum motivo (que eu desconheço) funciona perfeitamente no site no desktop & mobile, porém, dentro do App fica em looping infinito e não consegue achar a localização. Creio que seja algo relacionado as permissões, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A partir da API 23 (Android 6.0) é necessário solicitar as permissões em tempo de execução.

Veja se isso te ajuda:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br